# Add method to angularJs controller according the user permissions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if there is a way to expand my angular controller on the fly according to the user's permissions.

For example lets say that we have three different permission levels respectively (Admin,Supervisor,User) and an angular controller

```
app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function($scope){
   $scope.userFunc = function(){....};
   $scope.supervisorFunc = function(){....};
   $scope.adminFunc = function(){....};
}]);
```

I would like to add the supervisorFunc and the adminFunc only if the user possest the right permission.

- User controller will contain only userFunc
- Supervisor will contain userFunc and supervisorFunc
- Admin will contain all the methods (userFunc,supervisorFun and adminFunc)

Now I would like to add a separate js file that will inject the additional methods into the controller, so if you are a Supervisor your client will receive two js files, one is the main myController and an additional Supervisor Injector that will expand myController.

One important thing is that I don't want to dynamically generate myController js file at server side because it's bad practices.

any ideas ?

Comment: Can you explain how you plan on adding the permissions. That will help in understanding your question in a better way.

Comment: @ashfaq.p Basically the permissions are stored in the session (server side) and I add js files reference to the html accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea, and we do the same thing (sort of).

IF the second set of controller items does not have new requirements (directives and such), you should be able to do this:

in app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', ["whatever-directive", "some-service"]);
app.config(['$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
  ..
  ..
}]);
..
..
```

in controllers.js

```
function someCtrl($scope, $location, $http) {...}
function someOtherCtrl($scope, $location, $http) {...}
```

in onlyForYouControllers.js - that is only added if needed

```
function someCtrlOnlyForYou($scope, $location, $http) {...}
```

Like I wrote - you must declare what ever needed in the app to start with - even if it not used by a particular set of controllers.

Comment: that's a good idea but i want to extend the $scope of the main controller so that the injected methods will be able to use $scope like any other method